# Компиляция проекта C# без отдельных DLL

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

В С# я, грубо говоря, новичок, поэтому мой вопрос может показаться странным.

Можно ли как-то скомпилировать программу в visual studio, чтобы на выходе был один лишь exe файл? Без dll'ок, которые я туда подключал

Comment: dll - это библиотеки, а без нужных библиотек твоя программа может не заработать, т.к. в системе, на которой она будет запускаться отсутствуют эти библиотеки(

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос на анг версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)